# How to set a current date to datepicker in MVC?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a quiet simple question for my project in MVC, about jqueryui datepicker.

This is my class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit a user, this is my view page:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EntitiesList</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @value = @Model.UserName })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName )
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthdate)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthdate, new { @class = "date", value = @Model.Birthdate })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and in the end of the file:

```
$(document).ready(function{
$(".date").datepicker();
});
```

My only problem is that the current birthdate of the user is not showing, I'm getting in the editor text "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the current birthdate that is already set in the database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I got it... it just worked for me when I removed the value from the TextBoxFor.

```
    <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthdate)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Birthdate, new { @class = "date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
            </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.date').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
            });

            jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                var isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);
                if (isChrome) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
                }
                else {
                    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer on question is subject :

you can try doing this

```
$(".date").datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: not working... still getting "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the current birthdate

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        myDate=new Date(); 
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()-30);
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: not working... still getting "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the current birthdate. what is the "-30" that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this way:

```
$(".date").datepicker( "setDate", "@Model.Birthdate");
```

Trying to read from the model binding the date, and put `""` to read a "string" from the razor model binding. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting for a longer time and finally i found the solution which works for me. Hope it will help you to find out needed solution.
If your datetime is nullable attribute please use Model.ToDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
else use dont use Value.

```
@{
    var nextWeekDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
} 

<input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="ToDate" class="col-lg-12 form-control picker" data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" value="@(Model.Id > 0 ? Model.ToDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : nextWeekDate)">
```